# Reactive Input Parameters for LWCs on FlexiPages

Tags: lightning-web-components, public-reactive-properties

I am trying to create the most user friendly experience in an LWC.

I have seen the documentation for how to generate a picklist from apex like so:

(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags)
(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_dynamic_picklists.htm)

This creates Dynamic picklists, but how would I go about creating REACTIVE picklist inputs?

For example, in Salesforce's own 'Related List - Single' flexipage component,
If the user selects an option from the 'Parent Record' picklist,
the system uses the chosen value to generate the correct values for the 'Related List' picklist.

I have a few ideas on how to accomplish this but need a push in the right direction:

1. can you pass parameters into your datasource apex method? something like
   datasource="{!'apex://MyCustomPickList'+methodArguement}"
2. can you use if statements to control which apex method is being used? something like
   datasource="{! IF(myBoolean, 'apex://MyCustomPickList', 'apex://MyOtherCustomPickList') }"
3. I saw this buried in the documentation, but not sure if this is what I need or how to use it:
   "You can use VisualEditor.DesignTimePageContext to give your picklist the context of the page that the component resides on."

Any direction you could give would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be an idea out there on the Idea Exchange, but right now, dependent picklist options simply are not possible at this time.